# Get the first key name of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

Let's assume we have the following JavaScript object:

```
ahash = {"one": [1,2,3], "two": [4,5,6]}
```

Is there a function that returns the first key name for the given object?

From the example above I want to get `one` as a result of that function.

Comment: Do you want the value of the first key or the first key name of the object? I'm confused.

Comment: `let [first] = Object.keys(ahash)`

Comment: That question is not a duplicate for the another mentioned question, duplicate question is about "How to get the first property value", this question is about "How to get the first property key name".

Answer (score 639, accepted):

In Javascript you can do the following:

```
Object.keys(ahash)[0];
```

Comment: Works on browsers as well

Comment: this won't work on older browsers which do not support JS 1.8.5

Comment: I'd like to point out that `for (key in dict)` is likely to execute **significantly** faster, O(1) rather than O(n). It's not silly at all.

Comment: to future me... note that there is also a "value" method on Object, i.e. Object.value, if you instead want the value of the first key

Comment: @engineerDave, this is future you. We've changed our stackOverflow account handle and we've made a whole bunch of money by inventing time travel, but that is beside the point. I just wanted to say, "Thanks", this little note helped me out.

Comment: I get "ReferenceError: ahash is not defined (line 2, col 25)"

Comment: @cheesus: ahash is the name of your javascript object

Answer (score 67):

You can query the content of an object, per its array position.
For instance:

```
 let obj = {plainKey: 'plain value'};

 let firstKey = Object.keys(obj)[0]; // "plainKey"
 let firstValue = Object.values(obj)[0]; // "plain value"

 /* or */

 let [key, value] = Object.entries(obj)[0]; // ["plainKey", "plain value"]

 console.log(key); // "plainKey"
 console.log(value); // "plain value"
```

Comment: It does not seem to answer the question

Comment: An example using an explicitly constructed object such as the question used would provide a better answer.  This answer is basically correct, but it requires too subtle a knowledge of Javascript to easily decipher the meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks, changed to more understandable code.

Answer (score 40):

There's no such thing as the "first" key in a hash (Javascript calls them objects).  They are fundamentally unordered.  Do you mean just choose any single key:

```
for (var k in ahash) {
    break
}

// k is a key in ahash.
```

Comment: should check if obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) also I would add

Comment: and how to get the rest of other ?

Comment: I think it is not recommended solution. This uses bad feature named 'variable hoisting'. And ES6 has recommended not to use 'var' in for loop

Comment: The EMCA script specification makes dictionaries *ordered*. They are "ordered dictionaries".
The order of enumeration is the same as the order in which the dictionary items are added. This is useful.

in Python, for example, OrderedDictionary is a specific class, where Dictionary will returned indeterminate ordering of keys in dictionaries on enumeration

Comment: @JayDayZee ECMAScript doesn't have a thing called "dictionary", right?  This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/14343) seems to indicate that objects are unordered, and Maps are ordered.  Does that mesh with your understanding?

Comment: so javascript `objects` are quite complex things, that implement: a key value store; a separate numbered value store (array); prototyping. the `key value store` part is a "dictionary". * Enumerating keys (e.g. `Object.keys(someRandomObject)` returns the keys *not* an arbitrary order, *not* a random order and *not* some other specific ordering, but in the same order as they were added. * in Python, your answer would be correct, as there is no "first" key. (i would guess that the "ordering" of keys returned in python has something to do with the key hash)

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
for (var firstKey in ahash) break;

alert(firstKey);  // 'one'
```

Comment: Note that you must use the `var` keyword; `let` or `const` will not suffice.

Comment: No. Please don't do this. This might be correct but it is a completely hacky and confusing solution.

Answer (score 18):

If you decide to use Underscore.js you better do

```
_.values(ahash)[0]
```

to get value, or

```
_.keys(ahash)[0]
```

to get key.

Answer (score 7):

With Underscore.js, you could do

```
_.find( {"one": [1,2,3], "two": [4,5,6]} )
```

It will return [1,2,3]

Comment: Also true for lodash :)

Comment: there's also a `findKey` method which returns the key (instead of the value)

Answer (score 7):

I use [Lodash](https://lodash.com) for *defensive coding* reasons.

In particular, there are cases where I do not know if there will or will not be any properties in the object I'm trying to get the key for.

A "fully defensive" approach with [Lodash](https://lodash.com) would use both [keys](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#keys) as well as [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get):

```
const firstKey = _.get(_.keys(ahash), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put your elements into an array and hash at the same time.

```
var value = [1,2,3];
ahash = {"one": value};
array.push(value);
```

array can be used to get values by their order and hash could be used to get values by their key. just be be carryfull when you remove and add elements.