# Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?

Tags: javascript, object

If I create an object like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.prop1 = "Foo";
obj.prop2 = "Bar";
```

Will the resulting object *always* look like this?

```
{ prop1 : "Foo", prop2 : "Bar" }
```

That is, will the properties be in the same order that I added them?

Comment: also relevant: [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219/1048572)

Comment: [**The accepted answer here is no longer accurate. See up-to-date answers here.**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you go into a little more detail on why the accepted answer is no longer accurate?  The question you linked seems to boil down to the idea that property order is still not guaranteed per spec.

Comment: @zero298: [The accepted answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/157247) clearly describes the **specified** property order as of ES2015+. Legacy operations (`for-in`, `Object.keys`) don't have to support it (officially), but there *is* order now. (Unofficially: Firefox, Chrome, and Edge all follow the specified order even in for-in and Object.keys, where they aren't officially required to: http://jsfiddle.net/arhbn3k2/1/)

Comment: NOTE: `delete obj1.prop1` also does not guarantee the key order - see  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_notes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)

Comment: And now as of ES2020, even `for-in` has a defined order; I've updated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/157247) with the current state of play.

Answer (score 740, accepted):

The iteration order for objects follows [a certain set of rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/292500) since ES2015, but **it does not (always) follow the insertion order**. Simply put, the iteration order is a combination of the insertion order for strings keys, and ascending order for number-like keys:

```
// key order: 1, foo, bar
const obj = { "foo": "foo", "1": "1", "bar": "bar" }
```

Using an array or a [`Map` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) can be a better way to achieve this. `Map` shares some similarities with `Object` and [guarantees the keys to be iterated in order of insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared), without exception:

> The keys in Map are ordered while keys added to object are not. Thus, when iterating over it, a Map object returns keys in order of insertion. (Note that in the ECMAScript 2015 spec objects do preserve creation order for string and Symbol keys, so traversal of an object with ie only string keys would yield keys in order of insertion)

As a note, properties order in objects weren’t guaranteed at all before ES2015. Definition of an Object from [ECMAScript Third Edition (pdf)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf):

> #### 4.3.3 Object
>
> An object is a member of the
> type Object. **It is an unordered collection of properties** each of which
> contains a primitive value, object, or
> function. A function stored in a
> property of an object is called a
> method.

Comment: The behavior of integer keys isn't consistent across all browsers. Some older browsers iterate integer keys in insertion order (with the string keys) and some in ascending order.

Comment: @DaveDopson - Right -- obsolete browsers don't follow the current specification, because they aren't updated.

Comment: Is "Integer keys" correct? Based on my limited tests only whole number keys / non-negative integer keys are sorted in ascending order.

Comment: @cementblocks "integer keys" is a bit broad. It's really the "numeric array keys" of an object, which are basically keys between 0 (inclusive) and (2^32) - 1 (exclusive) that will be iterated in insertion order. So negative numbers, non-integers, and numbers equal to `(2**32) - 1` or higher will be iterated in insertion order, similar to string keys :)

Answer (score 324):

**YES (but not always insertion order).**

Most Browsers iterate object properties as:

1. Positive integer keys in ascending order (and strings like "1" that parse as ints)
2. String keys, in insertion order (ES2015 guarantees this and all browsers comply)
3. Symbol names, in insertion order (ES2015 guarantees this and all browsers comply)

Some older browsers combine categories #1 and #2, iterating all keys in insertion order. If your keys might parse as integers, it's best not to rely on any specific iteration order.

**Current Language Spec (since ES2015)** insertion order is preserved, except in the case of keys that parse as positive integers (eg "7" or "99"), where behavior varies between browsers. For example, Chrome/V8 does not respect insertion order when the keys are parse as numeric.

**Old Language Spec (before ES2015)**: Iteration order was technically undefined, but all major browsers complied with the ES2015 behavior.

Note that the ES2015 behavior was a good example of the language spec being driven by existing behavior, and not the other way round. To get a deeper sense of that backwards-compatibility mindset, see http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164, a Chrome bug that covers in detail the design decisions behind Chrome's iteration order behavior.
Per one of the (rather opinionated) comments on that bug report:

> Standards always follow implementations, that's where XHR came from, and Google does the same thing by implementing Gears and then embracing equivalent HTML5 functionality.  The right fix is to have ECMA formally incorporate the de-facto standard behavior into the next rev of the spec.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - that was my point exactly. As of 2014 all the major vendors had a common implementation and thus the standards will eventually follow (ie, in 2015).

Comment: By the way: [React `createFragment` API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/create-fragment.html) already relies on this... 

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Your comment is false. In ES2015 the order is guaranteed only for **selected** methods. See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/95735) of *ftor* below.

Comment: @mik01aj wanna link the source code from React that does? (yes, I'm being lazy)

Comment: @DaveDopson for point 1. it's only **non-negative** integer keys correct?

Comment: And here is the ECMAScript specification: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys

Answer (score 158):

Property order in normal Objects is a complex subject in JavaScript.

While in ES5 explicitly no order has been specified, ES2015 defined an order in certain cases, and successive changes to the specification since have increasingly defined the order (even, as of ES2020, the `for-in` loop's order). Given is the following object:

```
const o = Object.create(null, {
  m: {value: function() {}, enumerable: true},
  "2": {value: "2", enumerable: true},
  "b": {value: "b", enumerable: true},
  0: {value: 0, enumerable: true},
  [Symbol()]: {value: "sym", enumerable: true},
  "1": {value: "1", enumerable: true},
  "a": {value: "a", enumerable: true},
});
```

This results in the following order (in certain cases):

```
Object {
  0: 0,
  1: "1",
  2: "2",
  b: "b",
  a: "a",
  m: function() {},
  Symbol(): "sym"
}
```

The [order for "own" (non-inherited) properties](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) is:

1. Positive integer-like keys in ascending order
2. String keys in insertion order
3. Symbols in insertion order

Thus, there are three segments, which may alter the insertion order (as happened in the example). And positive integer-like keys don't stick to the insertion order at all.

In ES2015, only certain methods followed the order:

- Object.assign
- Object.defineProperties
- Object.getOwnPropertyNames
- Object.getOwnPropertySymbols
- Reflect.ownKeys
- JSON.parse
- JSON.stringify

As of ES2020, all others do (some in specs between ES2015 and ES2020, others in ES2020), which includes:

- Object.keys, Object.entries, Object.values, ...
- for..in

The most difficult to nail down was `for-in` because, uniquely, it includes inherited properties. That [was done](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-for-in-order) (in all but edge cases) in ES2020. The following list from the linked (now completed) proposal provides the edge cases where the order is not specified:

- Neither the object being iterated nor anything in its prototype chain is a proxy, typed array, module namespace object, or host exotic object.
- Neither the object nor anything in its prototype chain has its prototype change during iteration.
- Neither the object nor anything in its prototype chain has a property deleted during iteration.
- Nothing in the object's prototype chain has a property added during iteration.
- No property of the object or anything in its prototype chain has its enumerability change during iteration.
- No non-enumerable property shadows an enumerable one.

Conclusion: Even in ES2015 you shouldn't rely on the property order of normal objects in JavaScript. It is prone to errors. If you need ordered named pairs, use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead, which purely uses insertion order. If you just need order, use an array or [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) (which also uses purely insertion order).

Answer (score 80):

At the time of writing, most browsers did return properties in the same order as they were inserted, but it was explicitly not guaranteed behaviour so shouldn't have been relied upon.

The [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) used to say:

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties ... is not specified.

However in ES2015 and later non-integer keys will be returned in insertion order.

Comment: Chrome implements a different order to other browsers. See http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164

Comment: Opera 10.50 and above, as well as IE9, match Chrome's order. Firefox and Safari are now a minority (and both of them also use different orders for Objects/Arrays).

Comment: Perhaps we can clarify things by pointing out the cases where the order would not be kept. I.e., am I wrong or the only possibility is where your properties are numeric strings ?

Comment: @Veverke there is explicitly no guarantee on order so one should always assume that the order is effectively random.

Comment: Even though the order will be 99% predictable... all right, I agree that if the specs itself states that it does not take any responsibility in the order... we should not assume such a thing. Well, I rest my case then...

Comment: @Veverke No, the order is nothing like that predictable.  It's implementation dependent and subject to change at any time, and could change (for example) every time your browser updates itself.

Comment: I came upon this because I discovered code in ReactJS that to my surprise explicitly relies on this fact: ```   * @return {object} a key set that contains all keys in `prev` and all keys
   * in `next` in a reasonable order.
   */
  mergeChildMappings: function(prev, next) {
```

Comment: @Andy curious - can you supply a reference to the specific code?

Comment: @Alnitak yup, look at the `mergeChildMappings` function in https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/addons/transitions/ReactTransitionChildMapping.js

Comment: This answer is false in ES2015.

Comment: So, now with ECMA6 (ES2015) it's going to be fixed? So for all intents and purposes it's now fixed order?

Comment: I ran into the issue today that if your keys are numbers, the order is not preserved and the keys are ordered low to high (in  Chrome, at least)

Comment: @Alnitak "However in ES2015 and later non-integer keys will be returned in insertion order." Can you please either a) link to where the spec says this or b) edit your answer to remove this statement? It's factually incorrect & misleading as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Andy Dead link; I think [this is what you were linking to](https://github.com/Setsun/react-transition-group/blob/1d8fc7767a7b51019d27881d37d0abb524bdc135/src/utils/ChildMapping.js#L36), now in a different repo?

Answer (score 48):

This whole answer is in the context of spec compliance, not what any engine does at a particular moment or historically.

## Generally, no

The actual question is very vague.

> will the properties be in the same order that I added them

*In what context?*

The answer is: it depends on a number of factors. In general, *no*.

## Sometimes, yes

Here is where you can count on property key order for plain `Objects`:

- ES2015 compliant engine
- Own properties
- `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`, `Reflect.ownKeys()`, `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(O)`

In all cases these methods include non-enumerable property keys and order keys as specified by `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]` (see below). They differ in the type of key values they include (`String` and / or `Symbol`). In this context `String` includes integer values.

### [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(O)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getownpropertynames)

Returns `O`'s own `String`-keyed properties (*property names*).

### [`Reflect.ownKeys(O)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reflect.ownkeys)

Returns `O`'s own `String`- and `Symbol`-keyed properties.

### [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(O)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getownpropertysymbols)

Returns `O`'s own `Symbol`-keyed properties.

### [`[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys)

The order is essentially: integer-like `Strings` in ascending order, non-integer-like `Strings` in creation order, Symbols in creation order. Depending which function invokes this, some of these types may not be included.

The specific language is that keys are returned in the following order:

> 2. ... each own property key `P` of `O` [the object being iterated] that is an integer index, in ascending numeric index order
> 3. ... each own property key `P` of `O` that is a String but is not an integer index, in property creation order
> 4. ... each own property key `P` of `O` that is a Symbol, in property creation order

## `Map`

If you're interested in ordered maps you should consider using the `Map` type introduced in ES2015 instead of plain `Objects`.

Answer (score 28):

As of ES2015, property order is guaranteed for certain methods that iterate over properties. [but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/). Unfortunately, the methods which are not guaranteed to have an order are generally the most often used:

- `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, `Object.entries`
- `for..in` loops
- `JSON.stringify`

**But, as of ES2020, property order for these previously untrustworthy methods *will* be guaranteed by the specification** to be iterated over in the same deterministic manner as the others, due to to the [finished](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md) proposal: [for-in mechanics](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-for-in-order).

Just like with the methods which have a guaranteed iteration order (like `Reflect.ownKeys` and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`), the previously-unspecified methods will also iterate in the following order:

- Numeric array keys, in ascending numeric order
- All other non-Symbol keys, in insertion order
- Symbol keys, in insertion order

This is what pretty much every implementation does already (and has done for many years), but the new proposal has made it official.

Although the current specification leaves for..in iteration order "[almost totally unspecified](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-enumerate-object-properties), real engines tend to be more consistent:"

> The lack of specificity in ECMA-262 does not reflect reality. In discussion going back years, implementors have observed that there are some constraints on the behavior of for-in which anyone who wants to run code on the web needs to follow.

Because every implementation already iterates over properties predictably, it can be put into the specification without breaking backwards compatibility.

---

There are a few weird cases which implementations currently do *not* agree on, and in such cases, the resulting order will continue be unspecified. For property order [to be guaranteed](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-for-in-order#a-conservative-underapproximation-of-interop-semantics):

> Neither the object being iterated nor anything in its prototype chain is a proxy, typed array, module namespace object, or host exotic object.
>
> Neither the object nor anything in its prototype chain has its prototype change during iteration.
>
> Neither the object nor anything in its prototype chain has a property deleted during iteration.
>
> Nothing in the object's prototype chain has a property added during iteration.
>
> No property of the object or anything in its prototype chain has its enumerability change during iteration.
>
> No non-enumerable property shadows an enumerable one.

Answer (score 17):

In modern browsers you can use the `Map` data structure instead of a object.

[Developer mozilla > Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

> A Map object can iterate its elements in insertion order...

Answer (score 13):

### In ES2015, it does, but not to what you might think

The order of keys in an object wasn't guaranteed until ES2015. It was implementation-defined.

However, in ES2015 in *was* specified. Like many things in JavaScript, this was done for compatibility purposes and generally reflected an existing unofficial standard among most JS engines (with you-know-who being an exception).

The order is defined in the spec, under the abstract operation [OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys), which underpins all methods of iterating over an object's own keys. Paraphrased, the order is as follows:

1. All *integer index* keys (stuff like `"1123"`, `"55"`, etc) in ascending numeric order.
2. All string keys which are not integer indices, in order of creation (oldest-first).
3. All symbol keys, in order of creation (oldest-first).

It's silly to say that the order is unreliable - it is reliable, it's just probably not what you want, and modern browsers implement this order correctly.

Some exceptions include methods of enumerating inherited keys, such as the `for .. in` loop. The `for .. in` loop doesn't guarantee order according to the specification.

Comment: actually i test it out and yeah that is the way` js` handles array orders it sends numbers at top of the array with order for example `{99999: "John",1: "a",age: 30,696:'12312'}` will end up like  { 1: "a", 696: "12312", 99999: "John", age: 30 }
so mind your  number indexes

Answer (score 9):

As others have stated, you have no guarantee as to the order when you iterate over the properties of an object. If you need an ordered list of multiple fields I suggested creating an array of objects.

```
var myarr = [{somfield1: 'x', somefield2: 'y'},
{somfield1: 'a', somefield2: 'b'},
{somfield1: 'i', somefield2: 'j'}];
```

This way you can use a regular for loop and have the insert order. You could then use the Array sort method to sort this into a new array if needed.

Answer (score 5):

Just found this out the hard way.

Using React with Redux, the state container of which's keys I want to traverse in order to generate children is refreshed everytime the store is changed (as per Redux's immutability concepts).

Thus, in order to take `Object.keys(valueFromStore)` I used `Object.keys(valueFromStore).sort()`, so that I at least now have an alphabetical order for the keys.

Answer (score 5):

Major Difference between Object and MAP with Example :

it's Order of iteration in loop, In Map it follows the order as it was set while creation whereas in OBJECT does not.

SEE:
**OBJECT**

```
const obj = {};
obj.prop1 = "Foo";
obj.prop2 = "Bar";
obj['1'] = "day";
console.log(obj)

**OUTPUT: {1: "day", prop1: "Foo", prop2: "Bar"}**
```

**MAP**

```
    const myMap = new Map()
    // setting the values
    myMap.set("foo", "value associated with 'a string'")
    myMap.set("Bar", 'value associated with keyObj')
    myMap.set("1", 'value associated with keyFunc')

OUTPUT:
**1.    ▶0: Array[2]
1.   0: "foo"
2.   1: "value associated with 'a string'"
2.  ▶1: Array[2]
1.   0: "Bar"
2.   1: "value associated with keyObj"
3.  ▶2: Array[2]
1.   0: "1"
2.   1: "value associated with keyFunc"**
```

Comment: who still uses `var` in 2020 ?

Comment: `let` is not new `var`

Answer (score 2):

For a 100% fail-safe solution you could use nested objects and do something like this:

```
const obj = {};
obj.prop1 = {content: "Foo", index: 0};
obj.prop2 = {content: "Bar", index: 1};

for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++)
for (const prop in obj) {
    if (obj[prop].index == i) {
        console.log(obj[prop].content);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is O(n^2), probably not a great solution.

Comment: @MarkFisher I guess that's the trade-off for being fail-safe. However, optimization was still possible here: I have added a "break". Now it is approx. (n^2)/2.

Comment: I don't see any need for a trade-off in performance. How is Drew Durham's solution, for example, which could allow you to do the same thing as here in O(n), not failsafe? Also O(n^2 / 2) is still O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it doesn't guarantee order, but most likely, it orders by inserting items, but in some cases the order is change prone .For instance, if you use Object. Keys and Object. Values, the results of them aren't the same in first order. Likely

A solution to save order is to save keys and use those keys to access the object in the first order.

Something like this:

```
MergeFlatedObjValue(obj){
  const myJSONString = JSON.stringify(obj);
  const regexp = /(?<!:)("[\w.]+")/g;
let matches = myJSONString.matchAll(regexp);
var MergeFlatedObjValue="";   
for (const match of matches) {
  var matched=match[0];
   matched=matched.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
  MergeFlatedObjValue+=obj[matched]+"#";

}
  return MergeFlatedObjValue;

  }
```

Answer (score -7):

From the [JSON standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> An object is an **unordered** collection of zero or more name/value pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean, null, object, or array.

(emphasis mine).

So, no you can't guarantee the order.

Comment: this is specified by the ECMAScript standard - not the JSON spec.

Comment: @Alnitak, @Iacqui: JSON only takes this from the ECMAScript specification. It is specified for JSON too, but this does not really relate to the question.