# Accessing json objects within objects with Jade and express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I'm pulling my hair out a bit at the moment. I can't seem to figure out how to access the "media" content within the following json object using Jade.

```
   {
      "summary":"Jose Mourinho names his Real Madrid side to face Borussia Dortmund in the Champions League semi-final 24 hours early.",
      "type":"STY",
      "lastUpdated":"2013-04-23T16:31:39+00:00",
      "firstCreated":"2013-04-23T16:31:39+00:00",
      "hasShortForm":true,
      "media":{
         "images":{
            "index":{
               "67193384":{
                  "height":261,
                  "width":464,
                  "href":"http://thesun.co.uk/media/images/67193000/jpg/_67193384_67193383.jpg",
                  "altText":"Jose Mourinho"
               }
            }
         }
      },
   },
```

I can access summary, type, updated etc. But i cannot figure out how to access the image meta data within media.images.index.67193384

```
for item in results
    p #{item.summary}
    p #{item.lastUpdated}
    p #{item.media[0]} // ???
```

Can someone please help me figure out? I've never tried to access data that's an object within an object within an object. Also, the **67193384** object within *images.index* is **unique** and will ***always be different*** from result to result.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you making the JSON? It doesn't look right. Images is not an array. Also, using "67193384" as a key isn't helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a hack, but it works:

```
- if (item.media && item.media.images)
  p #{item.media.images.index[Object.keys(item.media.images.index)[0]].height}
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the following error `Cannot read property 'images' of undefined`. :/

Comment: Is there a check we can do to check if that data exists, incase it's missing for a particular item?

Comment: I added a check to see if `item.media` and `item.media.images` actually exist before rendering its value.

Comment: Nice! That's what i needed! Cheers buddy!

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in results
    p= item.summary
    p= item.lastUpdated
    - for (var key in item.media.images) {break;}
    p= item.images.index[key].height
```

The for loop is [used to get your key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298477/get-first-key-from-javascript-hash).

Comment: I seem to be getting the following error: `Cannot read property 'index' of undefined`. Which is a different error to @robertklep's solution :/

Comment: Is there a check we can do to check if that data exists, incase it's missing for a particular item?

Comment: `- console.log(dataToCheck)` ?